# How to use For loop with 2 parameters in robotframework?

Tags: dictionary, for-loop, robotframework

I have a keyword that has two arguments, one argument is a text I have to add and the second one is XPath locator. One keyword I have to run several times, so it's better to use for loop.

```
*** Test cases ***
TC - Delete item from todo list
  Add task to todo list  ${ADDED_SENTENCE}  ${TASK1}
  Add task to todo list  ${ADDED_SEVERAL_SENTENCES}  ${TASK2}
  Add task to todo list  ${ADDED_NUMBERS}  ${TASK4}
  Add task to todo list  ${ADDED_CHARACKTERS}  ${TASK5}
  Add task to todo list  ${ADDED_SENTENCE_AGAIN}  ${TASK6}

*** Keywords ***
Add task to todo list
  [Arguments]  ${ADDED_TASK}  ${TASK}
  Input text  ${TEXT_FIELDS}  ${ADDED_TASK}
  Press keys  ${TEXT_FIELDS}  ENTER
  Element Attribute Value Should Be  ${TASK}  value  ${ADDED_TASK} 

*** Variables ***
${ADDED_SENTENCE}  This is the first task I wanna do in 2021
${ADDED_SEVERAL_SENTENCES}  Long task.Long task. Long task. Long task. Long task. Long task.Long task. Long task. Long task.
${ADDED_NUMBERS}  1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
${ADDED_CHARACKTERS}  $%^&*!@#$(){}":>?<
${ADDED_SENTENCE_AGAIN}  This is my first task I wanna do in 2021
${NUMBER}  4
${TASK1}  xpath://*[@class="edit"]
${TASK2}  xpath:(//input[@class="edit"])[2]
${TASK3}  xpath:(//input[@class="edit"])[3]
${TASK4}  xpath:(//input[@class="edit"])[4]
${TASK5}  xpath:(//input[@class="edit"])[5]
${TASK6}  xpath:(//input[@class="edit"])[6]
${TASK7}  xpath:(//input[@class="edit"])[7]
```

I created a dictionary variable but for some reason when I use loop it does not take into account key and then value. Could you please advise what am I doing wrongly?

```
TC - Delete item from todo list
  FOR  ${i}  ${value}  IN  &{params}
    Add task to todo list  ${i}  ${value}
  END


*** Variables ***
&{params}=  {'This is my first task I wanna do in 2021':'xpath://*[@class="edit"]','Long task. Long task. Long task. Long task.Long task. Long task. Long task.':'xpath:(//input[@class="edit"])[2]'}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
&{dict}=  {'a':1, 'b':2}
```

is not how you create a dictionary. When I run this it gives me this error:

```
Setting variable '&{dict}' failed: Invalid dictionary variable item '{'a':'1', 'b':'2'}'. Items must use 'name=value' syntax or be dictionary variables themselves.
```

You can change it to:

```
&{dict}=    a=1    b=2
```

or use [`Create Dictionary`](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Create%20Dictionary) keyword. But since you're setting `${params}` in `Variables` section, this option is not possible.